# Class with **kwargs outputs: arg is not defined

Tags: python, class

I have a class with several arguments, and they have default values. In the program, sometimes a value used in the class would change with the input from the user.

I've thought about it the following way. The class accepts an integer named `group_size` (w/ 8 by default), a boolean named `bounds` (default: True). Sometimes, the user wants to change `bounds` and set `max_rank` to a different integer value provided by the user.

I have defined my class as follows:

```py
class Society:

    def __init__(self, group_size=8, bounds=True, **kwargs):
        self.group_size = group_size

        if bounds == True:
            self.max_rank = group_size
        else:
            self.max_rank = max_rank
```

But when I call it to change the value of max_rank, like this:

```py
S = Society(bounds=False, **{'max_rank': 10})
```

or like this:

```py
S = Society(bounds=False, max_rank=10)
```

I get the same error `NameError: name 'max_rank' is not defined`. With the first error, it points back to the same line of code, whereas with the other one, it points back inside the class where I'm assigning `max_rank` to `self.max_rank`.

First error:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-124-d093fc631922> in <module>
----> 1 S = Society(bounds=False, **{max_rank: 10})

NameError: name 'max_rank' is not defined
```

Second error:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-125-92d52166f851> in <module>
----> 1 S = Society(bounds=False, max_rank=10)

<ipython-input-123-ec1465ee15f1> in __init__(self, groups, group_size, b, c, fights_noise, up_rank, bounds, *args, **kwargs)
     49             self.max_rank = group_size
     50         else:
---> 51             self.max_rank = max_rank
     52 
     53 

NameError: name 'max_rank' is not defined
```

Do I have to (or can I) define the way **kwargs are accepted? Like the names the would take?
Maybe when I instantiate the class, I'm passing the kwargs in a bad way.

Comment: `S = Society(bounds=False, **{max_rank: 10})` gives an error because you didn't quote `max_rank`.  Try `S = Society(bounds=False, **{"max_rank": 10})` instead.

Comment: This `Society(bounds=False, max_rank: 10)` is invalid syntax. The `:` should be a `=`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to extract `max_rank` out of the `kwargs` dictionary

```
if bounds == True:
    self.max_rank = group_size
else:
    #Extract max_rank out of kwargs
    max_rank = kwargs.get('max_rank')
    self.max_rank = max_rank
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `max_rank` as an arg only just like other arguments and then extract it from `kwargs` method.

Here's the code:

```py
class Society:

    def __init__(self, group_size=8, bounds=True, **kwargs):
        self.group_size = group_size

        if bounds == True:
            self.max_rank = group_size
        else:
            max_rank = kwargs.get('max_rank')
            self.max_rank = max_rank

S = Society(bounds=False, max_rank=10)

print(S.max_rank)
```

Output

> 10